# Assistance with Kusto Query Language (KQL) for Identifying Specific Patterns in User Login Attempts

Tags: function, azure-functions, kql, azure-sentinel

I'm currently working on analyzing login attempts in Azure AD B2C using Kusto Query Language (KQL). I have a specific pattern of malicious activity where an attacker is using the same sequence of operations during login attempts.

```
AuditLogs
| extend OperationOrder = case(
    OperationName == "Validate local account credentials", 1,
    OperationName == "Update user", 2,
    OperationName == "Reset user password", 3,
    OperationName == "Update StsRefreshTokenValidFrom Timestamp", 4,
    0
)
| project OperationOrder, Resource, TargetResources
| extend UserPrincipalName = tostring(parse_json(TargetResources)[0].userPrincipalName)
| summarize Count1 = countif(OperationOrder == 1),
            Count2 = countif(OperationOrder == 2),
            Count3 = countif(OperationOrder == 3),
            Count4 = countif(OperationOrder == 4)
            by UserPrincipalName
| where Count1 > 0 and Count2 > 0 and Count3 > 0 and Count4 > 0
| project-away Count1, Count2, Count3, Count4
```

I've tried writing a KQL query to identify users who have undergone this specific sequence of operations but it does not seems to work as I am not getting the correct sequence.

Can I get some insight on how to modify the code so that it takes the correct sequence needed?

When I run the query, it shows results for individual operations, not requiring them to happen in a specific sequence. I want the query to only display entries where all specified operations occur in order

Answer (score 0):

The [next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/next-function) function can be used to search for sequences.

```
datatable (t: int, UserPrincipalName: string, OperationOrder: int)[
    1, 'a', 1, 
    2, 'a', 2, 
    3, 'a', 0, 
    4, 'a', 3, 
    5, 'a', 1, 
    6, 'a', 3, 
    7, 'a', 2, 
]
| where OperationOrder != 0
| partition hint.strategy=native by UserPrincipalName ( 
    order by t asc 
    | where OperationOrder == 1
        and next(OperationOrder, 1) == 2
        and next(OperationOrder, 2) == 3
    )
```